# How to encrypt folders and files for a wpf application

Tags: c#, image, xaml, encryption, directory

I'm working on a WPF project which is in charge to display a picture library. 
The pictures are stored on folders. 
I would like to know if there is a way to encrypt the folders and the pictures to protect the files (the user shouldn't see the files), but I want to keep the possibility to browse these folders by code to build my library.

Comment: How strong do you want the protection?  Zip files provide directory support.  Regardless, you will need to provide the key with your application to make it work, so it won't ever be entirely foolproof.

Comment: What type of project? What folders? Is this a deskop application where the files are stored on local system but you do not want the user to be able to open files from the explorer?

Comment: Anything that your code can do, the user can also do.  All you can do is make it harder.

Comment: The protection must be strong because the files are copyrighted. The user should not be able to copy these files. This is a desktop application.

Comment: What you're asking for (strong protection against hackers) doesn't seem possible.  In order for the encrypted files to be usable in your application, you have to include the decryption key in your application, and that defeats the purpose of the encryption, since anyone who reverse-engineers the key from your software can decrypt the files themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I can think of is to store the files and folders in a Zip archive with a password.  Zip files are supported natively by Windows.  There are plenty of options for supporting zip files, including [framework options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023350) and [outboard libraries](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/).

Note that this doesn't really protect the files from user tampering; it merely hides them from casual observers.  Also, there may be a speed penalty; you should use the fastest possible options for compression.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Zip archive and Another way:
you can add another  project project(Library)into your main solution,add your image folders into your application and set their `build action` property to `resource`,with that,your images will store in an Dll and for can access them from Dll.i tried it before follow this link:

[get-folder-address-in-dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319576/get-folder-address-in-dll)

Comment: It seems to be a good idea. I'm going to try it. But I don't know if it protect my file from a reverse-engineers.

Comment: @Ben:before put image in Dll, you can also for example convert image to binary (for example:get 4 first image bit and add them with a const number or make a formula for your self) with this way if some one open your Dll can not access them,and for show your image again reverse your formula for showing your image.i try it.

Comment: It seems to be a good idea I will try. The link you've posted is helpfull but there is no way to browse folder by folder and file by file. It's inconvenient to have only a Uri list (DirectoryInfo can't be instantiated using this kind of Uri).

Comment: How can I add my files to my DLL by code ? (After the modifications)

Comment: you don't need code,just add your images to dll project and set build action to embed resource

Comment: Ok so my images have to be encrypted before, I suppose?

Comment: No problem,maybe:before add your image to project library write a secondary small application to encrypt images, and after this add them.

Comment: I used this method, it works but it's very slow. I used another technique, which is to encrypt the entire dll, but when I decrypt the dll, I don't know how to access to my files because there are no url. With the first technic, the urls were like: `"pack://application:,,,/PTRS.Library;component/Images/Image.png"`
How can I find the urls with this second technic?